No compile time errors or warnings are being shown on my terminal window in vs code
I am using c language and I am working on windows using gcc compiler..I have also installed extensions like code runner and c\c++ Microsoft one too.
For example,
If I put an assignment operator in the if block then also no warning is being displayed
And if I use the wrong data type then also no warnings are there

Transcribed comment
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=2;
    if(x=1)
    {
        printf("x is equal to one ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("x is not equal to one");
    }
    return 0;
}

The exact command is gcc <file name>.c and the warning I am expecting (as I have seen in tutorials I watched to try to learn this language ) is "use'==' to turn this assignment into an equality."......and "place parenthesis around the assignment to silence this ....."

Assignment operators are permitted in the controlling expression of an if statement and in its substatement, and the C standard does not require a diagnostic for this. If your complaint is you expected enhanced warnings, then show a sample of the code you are compiling and the exact command line you are using to execute GCC.

gcc -std=c2x -pedantic -Wall -Wextra ... see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

https://godbolt.org/z/Go1ET45Ge ... using gcc -Werror ... or not :-)

Welcome to SO. Please do not put code into comments. It is not readable there. Instead put it into your question (as formatted text). You can use the edit button below your question to add your code. Please also add your compilation command.

BTW: The messages you mention, are no runtime errors. They are compile time errors or warnings.

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 
    int x=2;
    if(x=1)
    {
        printf("x is equal to one ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("x is not  equal to oneyhb ");
    }
   return 0;
}  
 The exact command is gcc .c   and the warning I am expecting ( as I have seen in tutorials I watched to try to learn this language ) is  "use'==' to turn this assignment into an equality."......and "place parenthesis around the assignment to silence this ....."

I've transcribed your comment into the question, but you should have done that.

Without any warning options enabled, GCC will compile almost anything without reporting on stylistic problems.

I will remember to do so in future thanks... and how do I enable warnings option...

@pmg showed how to do it — add -Wall -Wextra -Werror to the command line.  So you'd run: gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror <filename>.c (if you want to create a.out — add -o <filename> to create <filename> from <filename>.c).

got it....this solved the problem thank you i am sorry to bother you one more time but  I wanted to ask one  question can I permanently enable the warnings like without using these repeatedly....

One way is to create a makefile and set CFLAGS in that:
CFLAGS = -std=c18 -O3 -g -Werror -Wall -Wextra.
With just that line in the file, you should be able to type make filename to compile filename.c into program filename.  You can make the makefile a lot more complex, but that's a decent start.  You could also add a line: all: filename.  Then running just make will ensure that filename is newer than the source code.

I will try to do so....thank you!!
